# loopback 4 generate openapi.json on build

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I would like to generate an openapi.json file on a loopback 4 api without having to start the server and request the openapi endpoint. I could not find any way to do it in the loopback documentation.

Is there any way to generate that file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method getApiSpec() from rest.server.ts @loopback/rest/rest.server.ts.

add method in index.ts:

```
// Node module: @loopback/example-express-composition
// This file is licensed under the MIT License.
// License text available at https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

import { ExpressServer } from './server';
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@loopback/core';
import { RequestContext } from '@loopback/rest';

export { ExpressServer };

export async function main(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
  const server = new ExpressServer(options);
  await server.boot();
  await server.start();

  console.log('Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:3000');
}

export async function getOpenApiJSONtoFile(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
  const server = new ExpressServer(options);

  await server.boot();

  return server.lbApp.restServer.getApiSpec()
}
```

and create file for create json:

```
const application = require('./dist');
const fs = require('fs');


const config = {
  rest: {
    port: +process.env.PORT || 3000,
    host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
    openApiSpec: {
      // useful when used with OpenAPI-to-GraphQL to locate your application
      setServersFromRequest: true,
    },
    // Use the LB4 application as a route. It should not be listening.
    listenOnStart: false,
  },
};
application.getOpenApiJSONtoFile(config)
  .then(result => {
    let data = JSON.stringify(result);
    fs.writeFileSync('openapi.json', data);
  })
  .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
```

Comment: I tried the solution from you (with some modifications to get it running in the latest version of loopback 4. But it seems that the openapi.json file does not include any paths.

Can you give any advice on how to make it work in the latest version?